# How do I solve the error of the official canonical "Hello, world" example app of Tornado?

Tags: python, nginx, centos, tornado, uwsgi

```
My python version is 2.7.2
```

python is runing by uwsgi
my nginx config is

```
location /{

uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;

include uwsgi_params;

}
```

app.py

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(9090)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

then I run "I  run  "uwsgi -s :9090 -w app"

but it  throw a error

[pid: 28719|app: 0|req: 21/21] 118.207.180.64 () {38 vars in 716 bytes} [Sun Mar 23 22:44:34 2014] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0) AttributeError: application instance has no **call** method

how to solve it?

Comment: Can you link or paste your uwsgi config (/etc/uwsgi/your-app.ini)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tornado is an HTTP server, not a WSGI container (it can be used as a WSGI container, as in x3al's answer, but you lose some of its most interesting features).  Use the nginx proxy_pass option instead of uwsgi_pass; a complete example nginx configuration can be found at http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/overview.html#running-tornado-in-production

Answer (score 1):

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.wsgi
import wsgiref.simple_server

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    server = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('', 8888, application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

(from [official docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html))

Comment: no，it is still error and show "Internal Server Error"  the error.log is "--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---"

Comment: In the other side ,I don;t have xxx.ini like my_app.ini file

Comment: To use Tornado with uwsgi, move the `application =` line out of the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block (but not the lines dealing with `server` - either remove them or leave them in the `__main__` block).  However, using Tornado in this mode disables many of its most interesting features so you probably want to change the nginx config instead of the Tornado code (which I explain in my answer to this question)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing a tornado application as a uwsgi application. Here is the fix, using the `WSGIAdapter` available in tornado 4.0+:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.wsgi

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")


t_application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])
application = tornado.wsgi.WSGIAdapter(app)  # For wsgi layer

if __name__ == "__main__":

    t_application.listen(9090)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

But by using Tornado via the WSGI adapter, you lose some of the most interesting features that Tornado offers. Prior to version 4.0, [WSGIApplication](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication) was available.